# Server 2012 r2 core cannot change windows update to automatic

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-core

I have a 2012 r2 server. Trying to change over sconfig updates to automatic, the change will be fine, but when I open again sconfig is set to Manual. I was looking into GroupPolicy, which is set to index update (AU): 3. Eventlog without errors. how to change settings? thank you

Answer (score -2):

This is quoted from Microsoft support. http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/328010
On a phone atm and it's not letting me format propery.  Give me a few to get to a desktop and I'll update the formatting.

If you are logged on as a Computer Administrator or a member of the Administrators group, you may be prompted from the notification area to configure the Automatic Updates feature in Windows. 
For more information about the availability of the Automatic Updates feature and how to configure and use it in Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows XP, see Microsoft Knowledge Base article 306525: How to configure and use Automatic Updates in Windows.
For advanced users or IT Professionals, this article describes the following methods that you can use to configure the Automatic Updates feature: nullUse Group Policy nullChange the registry nullBack to the topBack to the top | Give Feedback nullConfigure Automatic Updates by using local Group Policy
Click Start, and then click Run. nullType gpedit.msc, and then click OK. nullExpand Computer Configuration. nullRight-click Administrative Templates, and then click Add/Remove Templates. nullClick Add, click Wuau.adm in the WindowsInf folder, and then click Open. nullClick Close. nullUnder Computer Configuration, expand Administrative Templates, expand Windows Components, and then expand Windows Update.
The Configure Automatic Updates policy appears. This policy specifies whether the computer receives security updates and other important downloads through the Windows Automatic Updates feature. By using the settings for this policy, you can specify whether automatic updates are enabled on the computer. If the service is enabled, you must select one of the three configuration options. nullTo view the policy settings, double-click the Configure Automatic Updates policy. nullTo turn on Automatic Updates, click Enabled in the list of options that appear at the top of the Setting tab.
If you click Enabled, you must select one of the configuration options that is described in step 10. nullSelect one of the following options: null2 - Notify for download and notify for install
When updates are available, an icon appears in the notification area and you receive a message that states that the updates are ready to be downloaded. Click the icon or the message to view and select the updates that you want to download. Windows downloads the updates in the background. When the download is complete, an icon appears in the notification area and you receive a message that states that the updates are ready to be installed. You can click the icon or the message to select the updates that you want to install. null3 - Auto download and notify for install
2683283Note This is the default setting.
When updates are available, Windows downloads the updates in the background. The user is not notified or interrupted during this process. When the download is complete, an icon appears in the notification area and you receive a message that states that the updates are ready to be installed. You can click the icon or the message to view and select the updates that you want to install. null4 - Auto download and schedule the install
To specify the schedule, select the appropriate options in the Group Policy Settings dialog box. If you do not specify a schedule, updates are installed daily at 3:00 A.M by default. Windows restarts the computer automatically if it is necessary. If someone is using the computer when Windows is ready to restart it, a notification appears that states that Windows needs to restart the computer. The user can choose to restart the computer later. 
If you select 4 - Auto download and schedule the install, you can set a recurring schedule. If you do not set a schedule, all updates are downloaded and installed every day at 3:00 A.M. nullOther Options
Additionally, you can select the Disabled option or the Not Configured option. If you select Disabled, an administrator must download and install any available updates manually from the Microsoft Windows Update website.
If you select Not Configured, the status of Automatic Updates is not specified at the Group Policy level. The status is either "enabled" or "not enabled." However, an administrator can still configure Automatic Updates by using Control Panel. Control Panel includes the same settings that are available in Group Policy. null2683283Note An updated Administrative Template (.adm file) is now available for use with the Automatic Updates feature in Windows Server 2003 and the Software Update Services (SUS) Service Pack 1 (SP1) client. This updated policy file adds two new policies: nullReschedule Automatic Updates scheduled installations
This policy specifies the time period that Automatic Updates must wait after the computer starts, before it continues with a scheduled installation that was missed previously. nullNo auto-restart for scheduled Automatic Updates installations
This policy specifies that Automatic Updates will complete a scheduled installation when any user who is logged on restarts the computer. If this policy is not used, the computer restarts automatically. nullThe updated client and policy file is included in Windows Server 2003. To download the SUS SP1 client for Windows 2000-based and Windows XP-based computers, see Microsoft Knowledge Base article Description of Windows Server Update Services Service Pack 1. 
To download the updated Administrative Template for Windows 2000-based and Windows XP-based computers, go to the Software Update Services 1.0 ADM File for Service Pack 1 web page. nullLoading policy settings by using Group Policy in Active Directory directory services
To load policy settings by using Group Policy, you must use the Wuau.adm file that describes the new policy settings for the Automatic Updates client. Wuau.adm is automatically installed in the WindowsInf folder when you install the new Automatic Updates feature. 
You can load WindowsInfWuau.adm as an administrative template in Group Policy Object Editor.
To load policy settings by using Group Policy in Active Directory: nullOn an Active Directory domain controller, click Start, and then click Run. nullType dsa.msc. nullRight-click the organizational unit or domain where you want to create the policy, and then click Properties. nullClick the Group Policy tab, and then click New. nullType a name for the policy, and then click Edit. nullUnder Computer Settings, right-click Administrative Templates. nullClick Add/Remove Templates, and then click Add. nullType the name of the Automatic Updates .adm file, for example, type windows_folderinfwuau.adm. nullClick Open.

to use group policy / local Group Policy to make these changes.  the registry to keep the changes.  While in an AD environment you have to use group policy / local Group Policy to make these changes.